# iso : get x、y、z angle when touch move

Tags: 3d, iso

I have working on rotatimg image when finger touch moving! and i don't know how to get x、y、z rotation angle when touch move happen. Does anybody know about this? please help, tks!

Answer (score 0):

By X/Y/Z rotation, I'm assuming you want some sort of trackball like control widget. To implement this you'd want to look into using quaternions.

For a simpler form of rotation leave roll zero, and map x movement to yaw and y movement to pitch...

```
dx = x - lastX;
dy = y - lastY;
rotation.x -= dy;
rotation.y += dx;
rotation.z = 0;
```

Then clamp the rotation so yaw movement doesn't invert

```
rotation.y = min(max(rotation.y, -pi/2), pi/2);
```

Alternatively, if you want to find the rotation around the centre of the screen as you drag...

```
midX = screenWidth/2;
midY = screenHeight/2;
downAngle = atan2(downX-midX, downY-midY); //angle from +x to start position of rotation
upAndle = atan2(upX-midX, upY-midY); //angle from +x to current position
angle = upAndle - downAngle; //difference between them
if (angle > pi) angle -= 2*pi; //keep angle less than 180 degrees in either direction
if (angle < -pi) angle += 2*pi;
```